# Node response hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a master method that handles my json responses, but the issue that I am having is that it hangs when I do.

This is what I had before I converted it, and it worked fine (`highscores` returns a `Promise`).

```
var main = {
    req: {}, res: {}, action: "",
    handleRequest: function(req, res){
        this.req = req;
        this.res = res;
        this.action = "Highscores";
        this.getAction();
    }),
    getAction: function(){
        $this = this;
        if(this.action === "Highscores"){
            highscores.get.highscores({gameId: this.body.gameId}).then(function(docs){
                $this.res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json; charset=utf-8");
                $this.res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                $this.res.write(JSON.stringify(docs));
                $this.res.end();
            }, function(err){
                $this.res.end();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I then converted it to this:

```
var main = {
    req: {}, res: {}, action: "",
    handleRequest: function(req, res){
        this.req = req;
        this.res = res;
        this.action = "Highscores";
        this.getAction();
    }),
    getAction: function(){
        if(this.action === "Highscores"){
            highscores.get.highscores({gameId: this.body.gameId}).then(this.respond, this.error);
        }
    },
    respond: function(docs){
        this.res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json; charset=utf-8");
        this.res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        this.res.write(JSON.stringify(docs));
        this.res.end();
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
        this.res.end();
    }
};
```

When I convert that, it hangs at `this.res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json; charset=utf-8");` and the chrome console shows that it is pending, and never finishes with a `200`.

What is causing this?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with promises, but I don't think the `this` pointer inside your `respond` method is what you think it is. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/jomk9axz/ this fiddle shows that the `this` pointer is pointing at the `window` object and not my `a` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass functions like that (`.then(this.respond, this.error)`), you're losing the context (`this`) for that function, because you are merely passing the function itself. So when the `respond()` is finally called, the value of `this` is probably set to the global context or some other object/value.

A quick and easy way to fix this if you want to keep the same structure is to use bound versions of the functions: `.then(this.respond.bind(this), this.error.bind(this))`. Otherwise you'll need to use a wrapper function that calls out to the two functions using the appropriate context (e.g. `.then(function(docs) { self.respond(docs) }, function(err) { self.error(err) })`) (assuming you have `var self = this` inside `getAction()`).